# PHP break for 60 seconds script, every 90 queries

Tags: php

Hello I try get value from bitfinex JSON. I need break script ever 90 queries, because in the documencation bitfinex API are informations [link](https://www.bitfinex.com/posts/188):

> If an IP address exceeds 90 requests per minute to the REST APIs, the
>   requesting IP address will be blocked for 10-60 seconds

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/symbols');
$bitfinex = json_decode($json, true);

$insertBitfinex = $this->code = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO exchange_bitfinex (`first_coin`,`second_coin`,`price`,`volume`,`volume_24`,`time`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

for ($j = 0; $j < count($bitfinex); $j++) {

    if($j % 90 == 0 && $j > 0) {
        sleep(60);
    }

    $symbol = $bitfinex[$j];

    $json_2 = file_get_contents("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/" . $symbol);
    $bitfinex_2 = json_decode($json_2, true);

    $first_coin = mb_substr($symbol, 0, 3);
    $second_coin = mb_substr($symbol, 3, 6);
    $price = $bitfinex_2["last_price"];
    $volume_24 = $bitfinex_2["volume"];
    $volume = null;

    $insertBitfinex = $this->code->bind_param('ssssss', $first_coin, $second_coin, $price, $volume, $volume_24, $time);
    $insertBitfinex = $this->code->execute();
    $insertBitfinex = $this->code->store_result();

}
```

My script is not executed correctly because it does not stop after 90 queries. I do not know if I am correctly trying to solve the problem using modulus `%`

Comment: the second part of the `if` condition can never be false, as the for loop only goes to `$limit_query-1`

Comment: Why not just check `if ($i==90)`

Comment: @SaadSuri because the value in JSON bitfinex is more than 90, so the script must stop every 90 queries

Comment: Well whatever the value is returned to you the loop will iterate over those values. Like `$limit_query` has a value of loop 120. The loop will iterate over 120 and increments `$i` so you can check `$i` https://3v4l.org/bhFgf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner loop does not use the modulo operator right. Even if it would execute more than the 90 times of the outer loop.

But besides that here is the problem with the inner loop.

```
 if($i % $limit_query != 0 && $i != $limit_query) {
```

When the loop counter is for example 1 the modulo operator returns also one (wich is not zero) because the rest from 1 / 90 is one. So it would do sleep on every cycle where $i cannot be evenly divided by 90.

The better approach would be.

```
if($i % $limit_query == 0 && $i > 0) {
```

This would wait on every cycle that is evenly divisible by 90 but skip the first one.

An alternative approach would be to the api call 90 times and then wait 60 seconds and repeat.

```
while(true) {
    //execute the loop for 90 times
    for($i=0; $i < 90; $i++) {
        //do something
    }
    //wait for 60 seconds to not exceed api limit
    sleep(60);
}
```

Or if you have to use modulo.

```
$some_big_limit = 10000;
for($i = 0; $i < $some_big_limit; $i++) {
     if($i % 90 == 0 && $i > 0) {
          //wait for 60 seconds, when the loop counter is evenly divisible by 90
          sleep(60);
     }

     //do something
}
```

Comment: Still wrong. `$i % $limit_query == 0` will never be true because its wrapped in a for loop that only goes until `$limit_query-1`

Comment: @alexeran sorry, but still not work, sript dont stop after 90 queries. I edit code in my post.

Comment: @michal: The variable you want to check if it is divisible by 90 is the loop counter. I see that you check the variable $i but your loop counter is the variable $j.

Comment: @alexeran yes, sorry my bad

Comment: @michal They also write _"Please note the exact logic and handling for such DDoS defenses may change over time to further improve reliability."_, that means that perhaps it's now less than 90 request, or maybe you're blocked for making 90 requests within few seconds, try adding a delay after each request (`usleep(200000);`)